# App Engine SSL Certificates shared across projects for admin inside one organization

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, app-engine-flexible

We added a custom ssl certificate to one of our projects. When going to other projects, I can see the same certificate even though it's not the same project, is it normal? All projects are under the same organization.
Thx a lot

Comment: Are you using an Organization? Edit your question with more details and context. Note: self-managed SSL certificates can be global or regional. IAM permissions control access to SSL certificates within a project and/or organization. Review the permissions **compute.sslCertificates.*** https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam

Comment: yes we do! I edited the question, so they would be all accessible under the organization